# Where to set 'overflow' value in FB Like Button...?

Tags: facebook-like, overflow, flyout

Its specified in Facebook Developer Docs that when user presses FB Like Button, the popup/flyout doesn't appear fully due to other HTML element, the 'overflow' property is hidden and it can be remedied by changing 'overflow' value to other than hidden. 
But where I can find this 'overflow' value? There is no CSS code given...!

Comment: Can you make your question more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your css:

```
.fb_ltr fb_iframe_widget_lift {
    overflow:visible;
}
```

If this is not working please post a link so we can see the problem.